# Could tfjs-models handpose return multiple predictions?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I've been looking into the [tfjs-models repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/) and its various demos. I've been interested into the [hanpose](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/handpose) one which  is apparently based on the [multiple hands tracking model of mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/docs/multi_hand_tracking_mobile_gpu.md).

However the [handpose module estimateHands function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/handpose/src/index.ts#L134) clearly estimates a single hand prediction.

I wonder how I could make it estimate at least 2 hands?

Comment: Have you run the code to see that it predicts only one hand ? Though I haven't run the code but I can see that it predicts all the hands available in the input picture and return a an array of bounding boxes with the probability of each like other pose prediction model

Comment: @edkeveked  I did run the code. You're right about it' supposed to return an array of bounding boxes but if look deep into the handpose sources you can see that it does return only one hand: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/handpose/src/index.ts#L165


But I'm still looking into the https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/handpose/src/pipeline.ts to see if it's possible to return more hands or not

Comment: There is this section in the readme " this model can only detect a maximum of one hand in the input - multi-hand detection is coming in a future release". So you cannot use the model as it is currently to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I actually found my answer inside the tfjs issues. This is not yet implemented and probably not trivial enough for me to achieve it on my own:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2942

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/pull/426